# Front Camera Video Capturing Distortion - Android

Tags: android, front-camera

I am working on Video capturing App. It is working fine for back camera. But when i switch to front CAM the video made is very blur (just some line across the video).

```
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

    mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_720P));

    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/myvideo.mp4");
    mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(600000); // Set max duration 60 sec.
    mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(50000000); // Set max file size 50M
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have searched a lot and eventually found the solution as below.

The BitRate,setEncodingBitRate,setVideoFrameRate,setVideoSize functions can have parameters according to your or user-end devices. I have used constant values working fine for me. Set them generic accordingly. Also, Remember that camera resolution is also set LOW for Front Cameras.

```
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(512* 1000);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(15);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(640,480);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSize( 200, 200 );
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/myvideo.mp4");
    mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(600000); // Set max duration 60 sec.
    mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(50000000); // Set max file size 50M
```

`Attaching Links which helped me to come to this solution.
[Blurr/Distorted video Error Insight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583371/android-recorded-video-seems-distorted)